# what does pipe and map do in anguarl?

Tags: angular

Hope evrything fine.

Iam trying to understand this code ?

```
return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:8000/api/Authinticate`, { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                console.log(user);
                //this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                return user;
            }));
```

what does .pipe(map do ?

thank

Answer (score 1):

`Pipe` is just using to tell "I will use one or more operator after this observable emits."

`Map` updates the data which is a value of an observable. Check the following example:

```
observableResult: number;

exampleFunction(): Observable<number> {
    return of(10)
}


ngOnInit() {
     this.exampleFunction().pipe(map(num => {
          console.log(num); // must be 10
          return 5;
     })).subscribe(result => {
         this.observableResult = result;
         console.log(this.observableResult); // must be 5.
     })
}
```

`of` operator returns a value as an observable.

For your example:

The code is sending a request to api and saving it to the `localstorage` and after doing it, it returns same user to the subscriber (where this function called from).

Also, there is a better operator to do it which is `tap`.
If you use `tap` operator instead of `map` you don't need to `return user`
statement. Because, while using `tap`, you can't change or manipulate return value.

Comment: it makes request very slow

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean. It is an async function and the time elapsed on request is up to your network and server performance.

Comment: it take 7 minit to log in bro

Comment: What do you see when you check the developer console? You need to make sure about which operation making it 7 minutes. Is your code making request too late or is response is late etc.

Comment: Its not the rxjs operators that makes your request too slow, and it won't ever.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe is one of the most important RXJS concepts to learn. Inside the pipe you can use many different operators that let's you do many different things with the values that comes through your observable. To give you some examples of what you can do inside the pipe:

- You can change the data to something else ('map' and 'mapTo' operator)
- You can throw away values that does not meet your conditions ('filter' and 'distinct' operator)
- Jump over to another Observable ('switchMap' and 'mergeMap' operator)
- Combine your Observable with another observable ('withLatestFrom' operator)
- Delay your value ('delay' operator)

Of all the more than a 100 operators available to use inside the pipe, the 'map' operator is the most basic one, and probably also the most used one. What it does is that it let's you run some code written by yourself to transform the value that comes through the pipe to something else. The value that you return from the map operator will become the new value.

So for example if you want to add 1 to every value that comes through the pipe you could do:

`pipe( map(startValue => { let myNewValue = startValue + 1; return myNewValue; })  )`